# How to create an incrementing variable with 2 variables in R?

Tags: r, increment, auto-increment

I would like to create an incrementing variable (Id1 or Id2) from 2 others variables (Var1 and Var2).

Thank you.
Elodie

**EDIT** (reproductible example for Aaron Montgomery)
I want to create an incrementing variable : "Id". The value of "Id" changes if VarA is a new value **and** if VarB is a new value. See in particular when Id = 4 in the expected table.

```
data_example <- data.table::fread("
VarA    VarB 
A1  B1    
A1  B2    
A1  B3 
A1  B4       
A2  B5   
A3  B6    
A4  B7   
A5  B7    
A5  B8   
A6  B9    
A7  B10    
A8  B10   
A9  B10")
```

Expected table

```
VarA    VarB    Id
A1  B1  1
A1  B2  1 
A1  B3  1  
A1  B4  1  
A2  B5  2
A3  B6  3 
A4  B7  4
A5  B7  4 
A5  B8  4
A6  B9  5  
A7  B10 6 
A8  B10 6
A9  B10 6
```

Comment: I can't follow what you're asking for... Can you provide your expected output? A reproducible example (in the form of code we can put into our R consoles, perhaps generated by `dput()`) would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
data_example <- data.table::fread("
Var1    Var2    Id1 Id2
604211  1001    3   1
604211  1093    3   1
604211  1146    3   1
604211  1319    3   1
635348  1002    5   2
634849  1005    5   2
620861  1004    4   3
622281  1004    4   3
622281  1041    4   3
600044  1100    1   4
600049  1033    2   5
607692  1033    2   5
612595  1033    2   5")

data_example %>% 
  arrange(Var1,Var2) %>% 
  group_by(Var1) %>% 
  mutate(id1 = group_indices()) %>% 
  group_by(Var2) %>% 
  mutate(id2 = group_indices())
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me. I have just edit my original question.

Comment: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument ".data" is missing, with no default." I think the group_indices function needs at least one variable as parameter, but if I put group_indices(Var1,Var2), group_indices(Var1) or group_indices(Var2), it doesn't give the expected table.